# How to add customized menu options in React toolbar using Electron App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, menuitem

I have a customized toolbar in Electron using React as shown below, with minimize,maximize and close buttons.

[image]

Now I want to add customized menu items like shown below (similar to VS code)

File -> New Text File, New File, New Window

Edit -> Undo, Redo

Help -> Get Started, About

Can someone tell me how to add such menu items in electron using react ?

**Titlebar.tsx:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { app } from "../../utils/services";

import favicon from "./img/logo.png";
import styles from "./scss/Titlebar.module.scss";
import {
  CloseButton,
  ContractButton,
  MaximizeButton,
  MinimizeButton,
} from './TitlebarButtons';
import MenuBar from "./MenuBar";

/**
 * @namespace Titlebar
 * @description Title Component to use as an Electron customized titlebar.
 * electron-window-title-text used in main.js to set opacity on/off focus.
 * electron-window-title-buttons used in main.js to set opacity on/off focus.
 */

const Titlebar = () => {
  const [maximized, setMaximized] = useState(false);

  const handleMaximizeToggle = () => {
    !maximized ? app.maximize() : app.unmaximize();
    setMaximized(!maximized);
  };

  return (
    <section className={styles.titlebar}>
      <div>
        <img src={favicon} alt="favicon" />
        <span id="electron-window-title-text">My Electron App</span>
        <MenuBar />
      </div>
    
      <div id="electron-window-title-buttons">
        <MinimizeButton onClick={app.minimize} />
        {maximized ? (
          <ContractButton onClick={handleMaximizeToggle} />
        ) : (
          <MaximizeButton onClick={handleMaximizeToggle} />
        )}
        <CloseButton onClick={app.quit} />
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Titlebar;
```